# Insert years dynamically to Morris Area JS

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I am trying to get some data of a mysql table and then insert it into a Morris Area.

The problem is that I don't know how many years I am going to get. Maybe I get 2 years of data or maybe 3.

Is there any way to insert that data to the Morris Area dinamically ?

```
(3) […]
​
0: Object { id_animal: 9, kg: "3", date: "2013-12-01" }
​
1: Object { id_animal: 9, kg: "5", date: "2017-01-18" }
​
2: Object { id_animal: 9, kg: "10", date: "2020-04-01" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, if you have a new data set, just call the function **setData()**. The number of years/lines does not matter.